# How to abstract a value from an object within an object?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, linq, object

I am a little stuck on how to get a value from an object within an object. I have tried numerous methods but cant seem to return the value.

var results return Json this:

```
{
  "Date": "2016-12-14"
  "Stats": {
    "A": 9.23,
    "B": 5.63,
    "C": 0
  }
}
```

The code to try and access "Stats" value:

```
 var apiResult = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
 var results = apiResult.DeserializeObject<StatsLA>(apiResult);
 object[] getValues = results.GetType()
     .GetProperties()
     .Select(p =>
        {
           object value = p.GetValue(results);
           return value == null ? null : value.ToString();
           })
        .ToArray();
```

The end goal is to loop through results and return only values that are more than 0.  In this example only "A" and "B" would return. I know how to do the loop/linq statement but first I need to get the values. Any advice would be appreciated, or just pointing in the right direction on how to approach.

This is the class file:

```
public class StatsLA
{
  public string Date { get; set; }
  public LocalStats stats { get; set; }
}
public class LocalStats
{
    public double A { get; set; }
    public double B { get; set; }
    public double C { get; set; }
}
```

Desired result:

```
{
  "Date": "2016-12-14"
  "Stats": {
    "A": 9.23,
    "B": 5.63
  }
}
```

Comment: I suggest using the `JObject` model with Json.NET instead of strongly-typed deserialization in scenarios like this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to `Deserialize` json to object, because when you remove the property from the json, the default value of your object for property `C` is still 0, which will generate same json.

Check [**full example at dotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ejfz78)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = @"{
  ""Date"": ""2016-12-14"",
  ""Stats"": {
    ""A"": 9.23,
    ""B"": 5.63,
    ""C"": 0
  }
}";


    JObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
    JObject statsObj = (JObject)result["Stats"];

    for(int i = statsObj.Properties().Count()-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        var propValue = statsObj.Properties().Skip(i).FirstOrDefault();

        if (decimal.Parse(propValue.Value.ToString()) <= 0)
            propValue.Remove();
    }

    string endResult = result.ToString();

}
```

If in the `Stats` object you have values different from type decimal, use `decimal/double.TryParse` and remove the element if the `TryParse` is true and the value of the out `double/decimal <= 0`.

Comment: @L.B okay he can use double.TryParse

Comment: @L.B he want to check the properties not only of Stats or ?

Comment: @user3515765 you can check the link there is working full example. Mark answer as correct if helped you.

Comment: @mybirthname `public static void Main()
 {
  Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
 }` is not a working example.... :)

Comment: @L.B sorry dontNetFiddle didn't save it. Check it now

Comment: This works great on fiddle however the class  isn't a string therefore sadly doesn't work. I use the class file to return results only for "A", "B" and "C" otherwise it will return "A", "B","C" , "D" and "E"

Comment: Don't use class like I wrote

Comment: but the result is dynamic not hard coded. I call an API and use class to filter what elements I choose to display?

Comment: @user3515765 you have property name Stats used it, it is not dynamic

Comment: if its not dynamic then how do I populate the json string in your example? I will try

Comment: no values returned :/ thank you for your help anyway :)